# Why are the links blue?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

I went to Skeptics to check out something and this is part of what I saw:

[image]

The links used to be black or some nondescript color. Now they are clearly not.

What happened?

Comment: Is this just me?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We had it on good authority that Bigfoots are attracted by bright colors, and so we temporarily changed the link colors to see if we could coax them out. But after an hour of yelling loudly into the darkness, it became apparent that our efforts were unsuccessful, and we've restored the former colors.

Our next project will be to scatter around some defiled bones on the theory that Bigfoots cannot resist a fight with annoyed ghosts. Please stay tuned...

[More details on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259185/problems-with-sff-and-seasoned-advice-se-css/259186#259186)

Comment: buht… buht… I kinda liked blue…